# vector field using green's theorem+other integration

Tags: integration, surface-integrals, greens-theorem

[image: questions]

So am I supposed to be using green's theorem for the first question, but where I'm confused is that there are three variables if I do,  dx dy dz (I haven't learn how to use green's theorem for 3 variables. Can someone show me how to do a) at least and I'll see how I can approach b) and c) from there (if possible show solutions to b and c). Thanks

Comment: Greens formula is a special 2D case, what you're after is [Stokes formula][1] more



  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#Kelvin.E2.80.93Stokes_theorem

Answer (score 0):

What you require essentially is the result

> A line integral from $P$ to $Q$ is indeendent of path followed Iff $Curl \bar{F} =0$ Iff integral is zero on any closed path passing through $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: How do I work it out?, I can't find the unknowns

Comment: Find curl F and equate it to zero

Comment: hi, my curlf turns out to be (c-5)i - j(4-a) + k(b-3). So if I set this to zero, (a,b,c) = (4,3,5)??. If so, for the next question do I just use green's theorem to calculate the integral?.